# Content of arraylist overwriting by another element

Tags: java, arraylist, jaxb, resultset

I have following code in a class.
When it processed it produces the xml with same value of tags which is in latest row of database.
I even tried reinitialize the object but it dont work

```
while (tempResultSet.next()) {
        conList = new ContentList();    
        conChannel = new ContentChannel();
        conChannel.setType(String.valueOf(tempResultSet.getInt("Key")));

        pubDate.setStart(tempResultSet.getTimestamp("PUBLISHSTARTDATETIME").toString());



       conElement.setPubDate(pubDate);
        conElement.setConChannel(conChannel);



        conList.setConElement(conElement);
        newConList.add(conList);

        conList = null;
        conChannel = null;
        }
```

Comment: Where are you printing(seeing) the XML file ? What is `ContentList();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a new `conElement` as well. It's getting reused/overwritten within the loop.

Currently, all your *new* `conList` objects have the *same* copy of `conElement` object that retains only the last values set via setters for the last row in the `ResultSet`. Do something like

```
ContentElement conElement = new ContentElement();

conElement.setPubDate(pubDate); // won't overwrite dates
conElement.setConChannel(conChannel); // and channels now

conList.setConElement(conElement); // every list has its own copy of element
```